# Specify Integer Precision gfortran

Tags: floating-point, precision, gfortran

I'm working with integers larger than 2^31-1 and so I'm trying to set the precision of my integer variables to a higher value.  The method I thought was correct was

```
PROGRAM f1
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER,PARAMETER :: LONG = SELECTED_INT_KIND(15)
INTEGER(KIND=LONG) :: n
n=2**31

END PROGRAM f1
```

which, as I understand, should allow `n` to be in [-10^15, 10^15].  However the above code throws a compiler error using gfortran 4.6, namely

```
n=2**31
   1
Error: Arithmetic overflow at (1)
```

I've tried replacing the trouble line with `n=int8(2**31)` but to no avail.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a near-duplicate of [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769095/real-data-type-fortran-90) so I should probably vote to close but here goes, again

In the expression `2**31` both `2` and `31` are default integers, most likely 32-bit integers.  The compiler will multiply them according to the rules for 32-bit integers, and overflow, before assigning the result to `n`.  If this is not the behaviour you want either fiddle with the compiler options (bad recommendation) or clearly set the kind for the literal values (better):

```
n = 2_long**31_long
```

(In practice you don't need to make both `2` and `31` `long` integers but it does no harm.)